# left join do not show all records

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, left-join

In following code left join do not show all the records from left !!!

```
select *,CASE WHEN (ResDEBIT> ResCREDIT) THEN (ResDEBIT) when (ResCREDIT> ResDEBIT)then (ResCREDIT) else 0 END AS Mande,CASE WHEN (ResDEBIT> ResCREDIT) THEN ('debit') when (ResCREDIT> ResDEBIT)then ('credit') ELSE ('ziro') END AS Status from(SELECT     Sales.CustomerInfo.CustomerInfoID,FullTitle=(cast(Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountFK as nvarchar)+' - '+Sales.CustomerInfo.FullName), Sales.CustomerInfo.TopicFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountFK,Sales.CustomerInfo.CompanyRegNo,Sales.CustomerInfo.PersonTypeFK,Sales.CustomerInfo.BankAccountDetail,Sales.CustomerInfo.BankAccountNo, Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountNo, Sales.CustomerInfo.FullName, 
                      Sales.CustomerInfo.Birthdate, Sales.CustomerInfo.TitleFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.RegistrationDate, Sales.CustomerInfo.CustomerPhotoFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.SocialNo, 
                      Sales.CustomerInfo.WebPage, Sales.CustomerInfo.JobFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.MaxDebitLimit, Sales.CustomerInfo.MaxChequeCredit, 
                      Sales.CustomerInfo.PreferedPaymentMethodFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.FirstBalanceKind, Sales.CustomerInfo.FirstBalance, Sales.CustomerInfo.Debit, 
                      Sales.CustomerInfo.Credit, Sales.CustomerInfo.Note, Sales.CustomerInfo.FinancialPeriodFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.CompanyInfoFK, 
                      isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit),0) AS Debit1, isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit),0) AS Credit1, (CASE WHEN (isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit),0) 
                      - isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit),0)) < 0 THEN (isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit),0) - isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit),0)) ELSE 0 END) AS ResDEBIT, 
                      (CASE WHEN (isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit),0) - isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit),0)) > 0 THEN (isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit),0) 
                      - isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit),0)) ELSE 0 END) AS ResCREDIT,Sales.CustomerInfo.BlackListed, Sales.CustomerInfo.IsActive
FROM         Sales.CustomerInfo  left JOIN
                      Accounting.DocumentDetail ON Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountFK = Accounting.DocumentDetail.TopicFK
GROUP BY Sales.CustomerInfo.CustomerInfoID, Sales.CustomerInfo.TopicFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountNo, 
                      Sales.CustomerInfo.FullName, Sales.CustomerInfo.Birthdate, Sales.CustomerInfo.TitleFK,Sales.CustomerInfo.CompanyRegNo,Sales.CustomerInfo.PersonTypeFK,Sales.CustomerInfo.BankAccountDetail,Sales.CustomerInfo.BankAccountNo, Sales.CustomerInfo.RegistrationDate, 
                      Sales.CustomerInfo.CustomerPhotoFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.SocialNo, Sales.CustomerInfo.WebPage, Sales.CustomerInfo.JobFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.MaxDebitLimit, 
                      Sales.CustomerInfo.MaxChequeCredit, Sales.CustomerInfo.PreferedPaymentMethodFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.FirstBalanceKind, Sales.CustomerInfo.FirstBalance, 
                      Sales.CustomerInfo.Debit, Sales.CustomerInfo.Credit, Sales.CustomerInfo.Note, Sales.CustomerInfo.FinancialPeriodFK, Sales.CustomerInfo.CompanyInfoFK, 
                      Sales.CustomerInfo.BlackListed, Sales.CustomerInfo.IsActive) CustomerInfo
```

Comment: I have 100 record on left table but it shows only 9 record !!

Comment: You are summing and grouping by. It is normal to have less records.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos let me know what is the solution to have all this columns with sum and group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check how many distinct record exists for your group by columns

```
Select distinct
        Sales.CustomerInfo.CustomerInfoID
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.TopicFK
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountFK
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountNo
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FullName
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Birthdate
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.TitleFK
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.CompanyRegNo
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.PersonTypeFK
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.BankAccountDetail
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.BankAccountNo
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.RegistrationDate
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.CustomerPhotoFK
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.SocialNo
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.WebPage
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.JobFK
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.MaxDebitLimit
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.MaxChequeCredit
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.PreferedPaymentMethodFK
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FirstBalanceKind
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FirstBalance
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Debit
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Credit
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Note
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FinancialPeriodFK
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.CompanyInfoFK
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.BlackListed
        ,Sales.CustomerInfo.IsActive
from Sales.CustomerInfo
```

the number of return records for your above query will be same...To get all records from your left table you can use any one of the below 2 methods but i would prefer the 2nd one
1)use sub query 
2)first do your aggregation in a separate query and join it with your left table again... the query should be some thing similar to below code:

```
;WITH CTE ( AccountFK, Debit1   ,Credit1    ,ResDEBIT   ,ResCREDIT  )
AS (
SELECT
    Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountFK
    ,isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit), 0) AS Debit1
    ,isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit), 0) AS Credit1
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit), 0) - isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit), 0)) < 0
                THEN (isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit), 0) - isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit), 0))
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS ResDEBIT
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit), 0) - isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit), 0)) > 0
                THEN (isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit), 0) - isnull(SUM(Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit), 0))
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS ResCREDIT
FROM Sales.CustomerInfo
LEFT JOIN Accounting.DocumentDetail ON Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountFK = Accounting.DocumentDetail.TopicFK
GROUP BY Sales.CustomerInfo.CustomerInfoID
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.TopicFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountNo
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FullName
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Birthdate
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.TitleFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.CompanyRegNo
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.PersonTypeFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.BankAccountDetail
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.BankAccountNo
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.RegistrationDate
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.CustomerPhotoFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.SocialNo
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.WebPage
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.JobFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.MaxDebitLimit
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.MaxChequeCredit
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.PreferedPaymentMethodFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FirstBalanceKind
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FirstBalance
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Debit
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Credit
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Note
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FinancialPeriodFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.CompanyInfoFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.BlackListed
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.IsActive
) 

SELECT Sales.CustomerInfo.CustomerInfoID
    ,FullTitle = (cast(Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountFK AS NVARCHAR) + ' - ' + Sales.CustomerInfo.FullName)
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.TopicFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.CompanyRegNo
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.PersonTypeFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.BankAccountDetail
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.BankAccountNo
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountNo
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FullName
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Birthdate
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.TitleFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.RegistrationDate
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.CustomerPhotoFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.SocialNo
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.WebPage
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.JobFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.MaxDebitLimit
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.MaxChequeCredit
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.PreferedPaymentMethodFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FirstBalanceKind
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FirstBalance
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Debit
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Credit
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.Note
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.FinancialPeriodFK
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.CompanyInfoFK
    ,cte.Debit1
    ,cte.Credit1
    ,cte.ResDEBIT
    ,cte.ResCREDIT
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.BlackListed
    ,Sales.CustomerInfo.IsActive
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (ResDEBIT > ResCREDIT)
            THEN (ResDEBIT)
        WHEN (ResCREDIT > ResDEBIT)
            THEN (ResCREDIT)
        ELSE 0
        END AS Mande
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (ResDEBIT > ResCREDIT)
            THEN ('debit')
        WHEN (ResCREDIT > ResDEBIT)
            THEN ('credit')
        ELSE ('ziro')
        END AS STATUS
FROM Sales.CustomerInfo
LEFT JOIN cte ON Sales.CustomerInfo.AccountFK = cte.AccountFK
```

Comment: worked like a charm , but please let me know If your code is better than mine in terms of performance and why????

Comment: I don't think there will be a big difference in terms of performance for a row strength of 100, but if you are working with a million records then you will get better performance by using cte.